# Coordinating Angular JS model changes via directives

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-service

I'm building a report viewer using AngularJS and am trying to figure out the correct method of handling changes to a report's definition via multiple directives.

For example, I have a report definition that looks something like:

```
vm.report = {
    dateRange: {
        startDate: "2013",
        endDate: "2014"
    },
    columns: [
        "id",
        "first_name",
        "last_name"
    ]
}
```

I have created various directives to handle modifying the report fields. For example, I have directives that allow modification of the dateRange via calendar pickers. And I have a column picker directive that allows the columns to be modified. Finally, I have a directive that allows the user to load a new report, or save the current report.

Currently I'm using callbacks with the editors to handle changes. For example, editors would be declared as follows:

```
<date-range-editor ng-model="vm.report.dateRange" on-date-range-changed="vm.handleDateRangeChanged()" />
<column-editor ng-model="vm.report.columns" on-columns-changed="vm.handleColumnsChanged()" />
```

This of course works, but I'm not sure it is ideal. Is it perhaps better to simply watch the vm.report for any changes? Or perhaps my directives should emit events that my controller can handle. What are the pros and cons of these methods? Are there any others I should be looking at?

Comment: You are binding directly to the models, so why do you need the callbacks?

Comment: I need to re-run the report when the report definition changes. But I'm not sure if just watching the report definition for changes is the best way to go here. For example, on the date picker, I want to re-run the report only after both the start and end dates have changed, not when just the start date has changed, but before the end date has changed. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

As you read in the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel),

> The ngModel directive binds an input,select, textarea (or custom form
>   control) to a property on the scope using NgModelController, which is
>   created and exposed by this directive.

ngModel is for `input`, `select`, and `textarea`. Thus, I would not use `ng-model` for my own directive.

If I were you, I would simply use the plain attribute, then $observe

Thus, yours would be like the this.

```
<date-range-editor range="{{vm.report.dateRange}}" />
<column-editor columns="{{vm.report.columns}}" />
```

Since you did not provide a plnkr, I can only abstract my thought like the following;

```
app.directive('dateRangeEditor', function(MyReport) {
  return  {
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      attrs.$observe('range', function(range) {
        MyReport.setRange(range);
      }
    }
  }
})
```

I have created [ng-map](http://allenhwkim.github.io/angularjs-google-maps) and I used this approach intensively all over ng-map directives. So far, I found this way simple and effective.

Comment: Good point about ngModel, though that isn't really the issue here. In your scenario, would MyReport be a service? And if I build my directives this way then I'm always tying them to the MyReport service. This is probably OK, but things like a date range editor could be used for non-report services.

Comment: @BrianVallelunga, you are asking now how directive communicates. You can use a service or event($emit, $broadcast) which meets your requirement.